# Retrieving all the possible options in a drop-down menu (when creating a work item) through the Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm in the process of recreating the Work Item creation UI in my web app. The UI includes a lot of drop down menus. My choice right now is either to hardcode all of the options available, or retrieve them and dynamically populate. I would like to populate them dynamically, but that would require me to retrieve the possible options for each drop down menu. Is there a way to retrieve these through the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this:

This document answers the question:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types%20field/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

We can retrieve the allowed values for our field through the API query GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}/fields?$expand={$expand}&api-version=5.1

My issue now is that the allowed values for one of my drop-down menu depends on the value of another. For instance, if I selected X in one of my drop down menus, the allowed values for my other drop down menu changes dynamically. I'm not sure how to handle this using the API.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct rest api for this. If you want to retrieve the possible WorkItem types in current project, you should `1.`first get the processID of current project and then `2.`list the WorkItem types in specific process.

If you're using rest api like your tags above: You can consider using [Processes-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/processes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#get-the-list-of-processes) to get the processID and [List Work Items Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/work%20item%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#get-a-list-of-all-work-item-types-in-a-process) to get the available WorkItem types in one project. We can't do that directly in one api, no matter rest api or client api.